# Log file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Hello can someone help me, I have a Python program and I would like to register the output numbers in a "log", but I would like to put all numbers, for that I used an open in the program and then I used a + = in the hope of na horade write in the file that the program skipped one line write on the next line, but the program gave an error, can someone help please ():

```
hora = str (datetime.now ()). replace (":", "."). split ()
hour = hour [0] + "," + hour [1]
   
name = "log" + time
    
log = open (". txt", "wb")
log + = "," + str (num)
```

This is the part of the log

Comment: can you share your code and full error?

Comment: There can be no space between the characters of an augmented assignment operator. Change `+ =` to `+=`.

Comment: Full code is long, more 1000 lines

Comment: Files are written with the `write` method. So, `log.write(b"something")` except you seem to also be suing `log` as a string and then `num` shows up somehow. I think you will have luck with a basic tutorial on python files. BTW, can you accept the edit and use code blocks in the future?!

Comment: Please don't post 1000 lines. The trick is to write a small working (or nearly so) example demonstrating the problem. What you've posted so far isn't enough to build an example answer from, imho.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Answer (score 0):

You've made multiple Errors.
`hour = hour [0] + "," + hour [1]` 
will give you an Error because it should be **hora** instead of **hour**.
Correct line:

```
hour = hora [0] + "," + hora [1]
```

Second Error:

```
log = open (". txt", "wb")
```

You should use text mode ("wt") as you're writing text instead of binary ("wb").

```
log = open (". txt", "wt")
```

Third Error:
to write in a file use `file.write()`
So

```
log + = "," + str (num)
```

should be

```
log.append("," + str (num))
```